# Subtract price on same Table

Tags: max, self-join

I have a table with below column Names. I want find result of        MAX(NewyorkPrice-MANITOBAPrice,0)

```
IntertieZoneName    DeliveryHour    Price   
MANITOBA              1             16.2    
MANITOBA              2            19.0 
NEWYORK               1             14.4    
NEWYORK               2             20.0
```

Expected Output on

```
Price   DeliveryHour
0       1
1.0     2
```

Please help me in writing Sql Query on Self Table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t.price_difference < 0 THEN 0 ELSE t.price_difference END AS Price,
       t.DeliveryHour
FROM
(
    SELECT DeliveryHour,
           MAX(CASE WHEN IntertieZoneName = 'NEWYORK'  THEN Price END) -
           MAX(CASE WHEN IntertieZoneName = 'MANITOBA' THEN Price END) AS price_difference
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY DeliveryHour
) t
```

Comment: Thank for your reply. I have this error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near 't'.

Comment: Reload your page, I had a typo in there.

Comment: Hi Tim, In result all price values coming as Zero.

Comment: Then your data has a problem.  Update your question _clearly_ showing what database you are using, what the table schema is and what output you expect.

Comment: And also There are many ZoneName in Table. i want to Substract ONTARIO zone name with other Zone names. example Ontario-Manitoba, Ontario-Houston, Ontario-Chicago

Comment: The inner query does the pivot, i.e. it leaves your with delivery hours and the prices for New York and Manitoba.  Not sure why you are having problems.  By the way, if you want to handle a dynamic number of cities, you'll probably need dynamic SQL.

Comment: I used UNION for each zone. I think my problem solved with Union. The only problem is if there is a new zone again i have to modify my query with UNION

Comment: Hi Tim, I extra column have been added to my existing table. when i use a new column in inner query, its Price difference returning Null value. Modified query : 
SELECT DeliveryHour,
      MAX(CASE WHEN IndexZoneName = 'ONTARIO'  THEN Price END) - 
      MAX(CASE WHEN IndexZoneName = 'MANITOBA' THEN Price END) AS price_difference,
     IndexZoneName AS IntertieZoneName
  FROM IESO_TRAPreauctionHZMCPMonthly t
  GROUP BY DeliveryHour ,IndexZoneName

Comment: Hi Tim, I am waiting for your reply

Comment: Thank you Tim for your help!